# Apache2 can't handle 200 concurrent requests with 8GB Ram and 4 core cpu

Tags: apache-2.4, performance-tuning, mpm-prefork, mpm-event

I am load testing a worpress site with [loader.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7b5J.png) , i am sending 100 concurrent requests per second, running the test in exactly 1 minute. The test fails considerably after 20 seconds or so, nothing logged on the apache error log,

I monitored ram during the test and ram seems to be fine, the server is not running out of ram.

Load average however shoots to 3.55 ,

am using apache event mpm , below are my settings

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    ServerLimit 550
    StartServers                     10
    MinSpareThreads          75
    MaxSpareThreads          250
    ThreadLimit                      64
    ThreadsPerChild          32
    MaxRequestWorkers         550
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
 </IfModule>
```

Below is a screenshot for `watch` and `top`
[image]

Below is a screen from loader.io tests
[image]

My goal is to handle 1000 concurrent requests, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Have you installed any caching in your WordPress? If yes, what kind of caching is in use? Apache2 is not the bottleneck here, but WordPress / MySQL.

Comment: No caching in place, i wanted to have a decent setup before putting caching in place. Are you suggesting that i should try and optimize mysql ?

Comment: I am saying that adding caching to WordPress brings most benefit in your situation. I recommend first to add that and then measure if your target performance level is reached.

Comment: in my less view and meaning you should also enable caching for mysql as it seems that it will hit hardly and the php oart is idling. so improving the mysql and caching is the first you will be forced to do and then start to test again

Comment: Aside from your values being too conservative, if apache is not logging all the accesses you may have some other connection issues, try ab locally before, and make sure OS system limits are not capping you. As for event, less processes, many more threads, just set 2 processes, and 300 threads each or so. Also differentiate static files and php files.